# Error converting '2021-05-30 19:00:00+00' into SQL Server datetime

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to convert a `varchar` column containing dates like `2021-05-30 19:00:00+00` to `datetime` before inserting it into a `datetime` column in another table.

```
SELECT CAST('2021-05-30 19:00:00+00' AS datetime)
```

But I get this exception

> Exception: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: This isn't a valid format for `datetimeoffset` either. Would need to be `2021-05-30 19:00:00+00:00` - then you can cast it to `datetimeoffset` and thereafter get it into `datetime` using your desired time zone

Comment: `+00'` that's not a standard offset. The string you posted is neither a `datetime` nor a `datetimeoffset`. What does `+00` mean? Hours? What happens with India then, which is `+05:30'` ? Minutes? Offsets aren't specified as minutes.

Comment: Where did this string come from? And why was a datetime+offset stored as a string in the first place? This is a **major** bug. In fact, how can you assume that the string wasn't accidentally truncated when it was written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`datetime` values don't have an offset. Assuming that your value, `'2021-05-30 19:00:00+00'`, is coming from a variable/column then truncate the offset from the value, and then use an explicit style:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,LEFT('2021-05-30 19:00:00+00',19),121);
```

If you want to maintain the offset, add the minutes:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(datetimeoffset(0),'2021-05-30 19:00:00+00'+':00',121);
```

Comment: This assumes the offset is hours instead of minutes. `+00` won't handle half-hour offsets like India's. The OP's custom notation isn't a very good idea

Comment: `+00` wouldn't handle all of the world's offsets, @PanagiotisKanavos. I *assume* it's hours, as minutes just wouldn't work. Unless it's +/- 1 hour, you can't fit the digits in. But the flaw is the OP's data.

Comment: As I said, a bad idea that looks worse by the minute. Since the field was a `varchar` how do we (or the OP) know the value is valid at all? It may have been truncated.

Comment: The data is being fetched using one of the google api's that returns a json with offset as +00, trying to find what this format represents. I think for now i will truncate the as suggested. This will be a temporary solution to test the remaining  functionality .

Comment: The only [example](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/json#json) I can see for JSON from the Google API using `Z` as the timezone, @Sam .

Answer (score -1):

Problem with the above cast is the Time Zone.  if you need to change the Time Zone then your code will have to use CONVERT_TZ.

```sql
/* works with mysql 5+ */
select CAST('2021-05-30 19:00:00' as DATETIME);
```

Using a substring to remove the time zone and cast it to

```sql
select cast((SUBSTRING_INDEX('2021-05-30 19:00:00+00','+',1)) as DATETIME);
```

you can also use convert the date time to the system time zone using CONVERT_TZ but why would you change the time zone to what your system is using,

```sql
SELECT CAST(CONVERT_TZ(CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX('2021-05-30 19:00:00+00','+',1) AS DATETIME),CONCAT('+',CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('21-05-30 19:00:00+00','+',-1),':00')),@@session.time_zone) AS DATETIME);
```

Comment: Apart from the OP is using SQL Server, *not* MySQL...